# Problems with network routing

Tags: networking, routing, cisco-vpn, ip-routing

Could you help, please?
I have two network interfaces:
1) Physical interface (12)
2) Virtual VPN interface (39)

Without VPN connection I have access to my local network (for example: 192.168.160.35)
But after VPN connected I don't have it. I increased metric for virtual interface intentionally. I don't understand why all traffic still goes through virtual VPN interface.
I need access to my local network while VPN connected.
Please, help!

Have a look my routing table before VPN connected and after.
(Sorry for russian locale)

Before VPN connected.

```
C:\Users\test_user>route print
===========================================================================
Список интерфейсов
 22...54 e8 0e b1 3e 23 ......Check Point Virtual Network Adapter For Endpoint VPN Client
 57...00 ff 2b 76 3d ac ......TeamViewer VPN Adapter
 21...00 26 c7 82 48 0b ......Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter
 20...5c ac 4c c9 b5 a5 ......Устройства Bluetooth (личной сети) #3
 18...00 26 c7 82 48 0a ......Intel(R) WiFi Link 1000 BGN
 12...f0 de f1 2b 12 63 ......Intel(R) 82577LM Gigabit Network Connection
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 30...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Адаптер Microsoft ISATAP
 55...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Адаптер Microsoft ISATAP #2
 26...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Адаптер Microsoft ISATAP #3
 27...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Адаптер Microsoft ISATAP #4
 56...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Адаптер Microsoft ISATAP #5
 60...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Адаптер Microsoft ISATAP #6
 28...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
 25...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Адаптер Microsoft ISATAP #9
===========================================================================

IPv4 таблица маршрута
===========================================================================
Активные маршруты:
Сетевой адрес           Маска сети      Адрес шлюза       Интерфейс  Метрика
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0  192.168.134.129  192.168.134.165     20
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  192.168.134.128  255.255.255.192         On-link   192.168.134.165    276
  192.168.134.165  255.255.255.255         On-link   192.168.134.165    276
  192.168.134.191  255.255.255.255         On-link   192.168.134.165    276
   192.168.160.35  255.255.255.255  192.168.134.129  192.168.134.165     21
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link   192.168.134.165    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link   192.168.134.165    276
===========================================================================
Постоянные маршруты:
  Отсутствует

IPv6 таблица маршрута
===========================================================================
Активные маршруты:
 Метрика   Сетевой адрес            Шлюз
 12    276 ::/0                     fe80::32:51d9:21cd:4786
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
 12    276 fe80::/64                On-link
 12    276 fe80::e084:21a6:311f:a6c4/128
                                    On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
 12    276 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Постоянные маршруты:
  Отсутствует

C:\Users\test_user>ping 192.168.160.35

Обмен пакетами с 192.168.160.35 по с 32 байтами данных:
Ответ от 192.168.160.35: число байт=32 время<1мс TTL=62
Ответ от 192.168.160.35: число байт=32 время<1мс TTL=62
Ответ от 192.168.160.35: число байт=32 время<1мс TTL=62
Ответ от 192.168.160.35: число байт=32 время<1мс TTL=62

Статистика Ping для 192.168.160.35:
    Пакетов: отправлено = 4, получено = 4, потеряно = 0
    (0% потерь)
Приблизительное время приема-передачи в мс:
    Минимальное = 0мсек, Максимальное = 0 мсек, Среднее = 0 мсек

C:\Users\test_user>tracert google.com

Трассировка маршрута к google.com [173.194.69.100]
с максимальным числом прыжков 30:

  1     *        *        *     Превышен интервал ожидания для запроса.
  2     *        *        *     Превышен интервал ожидания для запроса.
  3     *        *        *     Превышен интервал ожидания для запроса.
  4     *        *        *     Превышен интервал ожидания для запроса.
  5     *        *        *     Превышен интервал ожидания для запроса.
  6     *        *        *     Превышен интервал ожидания для запроса.
  7     *        *        *     Превышен интервал ожидания для запроса.
  8     *        *     ^C
```

After VPN connected:

```
C:\Users\test_user>route print
===========================================================================
Список интерфейсов
 22...54 e8 0e b1 3e 23 ......Check Point Virtual Network Adapter For Endpoint VPN Client
 57...00 ff 2b 76 3d ac ......TeamViewer VPN Adapter
 39...00 05 9a 3c 78 00 ......Cisco Systems VPN Adapter
 21...00 26 c7 82 48 0b ......Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter
 20...5c ac 4c c9 b5 a5 ......Устройства Bluetooth (личной сети) #3
 18...00 26 c7 82 48 0a ......Intel(R) WiFi Link 1000 BGN
 12...f0 de f1 2b 12 63 ......Intel(R) 82577LM Gigabit Network Connection
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 30...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Адаптер Microsoft ISATAP
 55...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Адаптер Microsoft ISATAP #2
 26...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Адаптер Microsoft ISATAP #3
 27...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Адаптер Microsoft ISATAP #4
 56...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Адаптер Microsoft ISATAP #5
 60...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Адаптер Microsoft ISATAP #6
 28...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
 25...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Адаптер Microsoft ISATAP #9
===========================================================================

IPv4 таблица маршрута
===========================================================================
Активные маршруты:
Сетевой адрес           Маска сети      Адрес шлюза       Интерфейс  Метрика
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0  192.168.134.129  192.168.134.165     20
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    192.168.227.1  192.168.227.122    501
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
   192.168.134.52  255.255.255.255  192.168.134.129  192.168.134.165    100
  192.168.134.128  255.255.255.192         On-link   192.168.134.165    276
  192.168.134.165  255.255.255.255         On-link   192.168.134.165    276
  192.168.134.191  255.255.255.255         On-link   192.168.134.165    276
    192.168.227.0    255.255.255.0         On-link   192.168.227.122    756
  192.168.227.122  255.255.255.255         On-link   192.168.227.122    756
  192.168.227.255  255.255.255.255         On-link   192.168.227.122    756
  213.138.128.163  255.255.255.255  192.168.134.129  192.168.134.165    100
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link   192.168.134.165    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link   192.168.227.122    756
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link   192.168.134.165    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link   192.168.227.122    756
===========================================================================
Постоянные маршруты:
  Сетевой адрес            Маска    Адрес шлюза      Метрика
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    192.168.227.1       1
===========================================================================

IPv6 таблица маршрута
===========================================================================
Активные маршруты:
 Метрика   Сетевой адрес            Шлюз
 12    276 ::/0                     fe80::32:51d9:21cd:4786
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
 12    276 fe80::/64                On-link
 39    276 fe80::/64                On-link
 39    276 fe80::75bb:3b7a:8c12:4023/128
                                    On-link
 12    276 fe80::e084:21a6:311f:a6c4/128
                                    On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
 12    276 ff00::/8                 On-link
 39    276 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Постоянные маршруты:
  Отсутствует

C:\Users\test_user>ping 192.168.160.35

Обмен пакетами с 192.168.160.35 по с 32 байтами данных:
Превышен интервал ожидания для запроса.
Превышен интервал ожидания для запроса.
Превышен интервал ожидания для запроса.
Превышен интервал ожидания для запроса.

Статистика Ping для 192.168.160.35:
    Пакетов: отправлено = 4, получено = 0, потеряно = 4
    (100% потерь)

C:\Users\test_user>tracert google.com

Трассировка маршрута к google.com [173.194.32.7]
с максимальным числом прыжков 30:

  1    91 ms   207 ms   111 ms  213138128164.edelkey.net [213.138.128.164]
  2    91 ms    90 ms    90 ms  172.16.67.1
  3     *        *        *     Превышен интервал ожидания для запроса.
  4    90 ms    90 ms    90 ms  195.237.145.33
  5    93 ms    91 ms    94 ms  172.16.134.97
  6    90 ms    90 ms    91 ms  xe3-1-0.helpa-p2.fi.elisa.net [139.97.16.77]
  7    91 ms    90 ms    90 ms  ae1.helpa-gw1.fi.elisa.net [139.97.6.242]
  8    91 ms    91 ms    91 ms  ae1-10.bbr1.hel2.fi.eunetip.net [213.192.191.53]
  9    98 ms    98 ms    98 ms  ae1-0.bbr1.sto1.se.eunetip.net [213.192.184.45]
 10    97 ms    98 ms    98 ms  74.125.50.145
 11    98 ms    98 ms   100 ms  209.85.250.192
 12    98 ms    99 ms    98 ms  216.239.43.253
 13     *       98 ms    98 ms  arn06s01-in-f7.1e100.net [173.194.32.7]

Трассировка завершена.

C:\Users\test_user>
```

Comment: RTFM - `route change`

Answer (score 1):

What VPN client are you  using?  I think the in-built Windows one uses the gateway on the VPN network by default, so there's a setting you need to modify.
If you go to the VPN properties > networking tab > highlight IPv4 and click properties > advanced > use default gateway on remote network (untick).

Comment: I use Cisco VPN client 5.0.07.0410

Comment: I found the option "Allow local LAN Access" on the Tab "Transport" in connecton properties. This option is active. But local network is unreachable.

Comment: I've not used that client before.  This question (http://superuser.com/questions/284709/how-to-allow-local-lan-access-while-connected-to-cisco-vpn) and the associated links suggest the VPN client overrides the default Windows routing behaviour if the VPN server is set up to do so.  You can try adding a static route for the internal subnet (192.168.160.x is different from what's currently in your routing table) so it doesn't fall to the default gateway.

Comment: Thanks, Demelziraptor! As I read at another topics it seems to be cisco VPN client is tunneling all traffic through the VPN server. And there is one way to solve the problem  - configurate cisco VPN server switching on split-tunneling.